# Want to https://www.example.org to https://example.org in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, web, server, dns

I want to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com in Nginx.

I tried to do this using with below code, but I have to redirect multiple domains so can't mention specific "example.com" in the return line. I have around 30 different domains for which this need to be done.

I have gone through many suggested solutions but all are with one domain which doesn't meet my requirement. Like if there are domains (example.com,example.com,xyz.com etc) all need to redirect to https://respectivedomain(non-www)

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # redirects www to non-www. wasn't work for me without this server block
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Update:**

```
server {
    server_name "www.(.+?\.\w+)" ;
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}
```

I tried the above code but still, there is an error "*NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*".

The site is working with below

```
example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

but not with adding www to a domain, SSL certificate is issued to non-www domain

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using configuration below.

**Single domain**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Multiple domains**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
}
```

[source](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/www-non-www-redirection/)

Comment: I tried the above code as well modify it below, but still, there is an error "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID". 
The site is working with below
example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com

but not with adding www to a domain, SSL is an issue to non-www domain


server {
    server_name "www.(.+?\.\w+)" ;
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}

Comment: that is ssl certificate problem, your ssl certificate must include all domain you use, include www and non-www.

Comment: When I try to run the site http://www.example.com it redirects to https://example.com but when I try with https://www.example.com there is an error "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"". This scenario is without any change

Comment: the common name on your certificate does not match the domain it’s installed on, make sure your ssl certificate include your domain name.

Comment: the certificate has "example.com" but not "www.example.com"